# Let $A$ be an infinite set of disjoint open sub intervals of $(0,1)$. Let $B$ be the power set of $A$. Then .......

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be an infinite set of disjoint open sub intervals of $(0,1)$. Let $B$ be the power set of $A$. Then

1. Cardinality of $A,B$ are equal.
2. $A$ is similar to $(0,1)$
3. $B$ is similar to $(0,1)$
4. $A,B$ both are uncountable

I know that $A$ is countable. How to conclude about $B$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hello :) you're right. $A$ is countable, because for every $x\in \mathbb Q$, there is at most one interval, that contains $x$. Further, there is no interval, that contains only irrationals. Since, there are infinitely many open intervals in $A$, we have $|A|=|\mathbb N|$ and $|B|=|P(A) |=|P(\mathbb N) |$. By Cantor's theorem, we get $|B|=|P(\mathbb N) |=|\mathbb R|=(0, 1) |$.